# IPython autocomplete not working for functions returning a dynamic object

Tags: python, ipython

I'm having troubles to get the IPython 7.13.0 autocomplete feature working for dynamically generated classes. Here is an example:

```
Foo = type('obj', (object,), {})
def bar(this, text):
    print(text)
setattr(Foo, 'bar', bar)
```

The autocomplete feature works so far:

```
Foo().b TAB
Foo().bar
```

Next we create a class `Foobar` with a function called `foo` in which we return an object of `Foo`.

```
class Foobar:
    def foo(self):
        return Foo()
```

When now trying to autocomplete the return value of the `foo` function it does not work as one might expect:

```
Foobar().f TAB
Foobar().foo
Foobar().foo().b TAB
```

Is there a way to let the IPython autocomplete feature know what to return here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. IPython doesn't know the return type of methods, but it does know about class instantiation.

Comment: i was hoping to do something like ```setattr(Foobar.foo, '__all__', lambda: ["bar"])``` or ```setattr(Foobar.foo, '__dir__', lambda: ["bar"])``` or using any kind of hook or custom completer ... Currently i'm browsing the IPython source code but with little success so far.